# create the three edge models and compute the gradient magnitude using sobel mask and sketch horizontal intensity profile

Tags: sobel

Create the three edge models and compute the gradient magnitude using sobel mask. Sketch the horizontal intensity profiles. Sketch the horizontal intensity profiles of the laplacian images

Comment: what is the question? "How to..."?